# Closed form for nth term of generating function

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, closed-form

How would I find the closed form for the $n^{th}$ term of a sequence? Is there a general formula I can follow for these types of problems? Taking this sequence for example...

$$\frac{x^5}{(1-x)^4}$$

Answer (score 1):

You divide out by the $x^{5}$ term, and so the coefficient of $x^{n}$ on the function you provided is the same as the coefficient of $x^{n-5}$ on $\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^{4}}$.

And so $\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^{4}} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \binom{4 + i - 1}{i} x^{i}$.

So the coefficient of $x^{n}$ is $\binom{4 + n - 6}{n-5}$.

Comment: Why are you giving the coefficient? Doesn't the question ask to write out the sequence for the nth term?

Comment: Generating functions are expanded out using binomial coefficients. The coefficient returns the count for $n$ elements. If you want the counts for terms $n = 1, ..., k$, then you list out the coefficients for $x^{1}, ..., x^{k}$.